# Unable to get Saved shared preferences in the fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, sharedpreferences

I am working on a app and while getting my shared preferences(which are saved in login activity), i am trying to get it in dashboard fragment but i am not be able to get it. After this i checked whether the is saved or not so then i used

```
boolean ok= editor.commit();
Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Saved: "+ok, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My toast shows message as **Saved:true**

After this try i am assuming that my data is saved to preferecnces but i am unable to fetch it. Below is my dashboard fragmenr code.

```
public class dashboard extends Fragment {
private TextView comp_text,mail_text,gst_text;
private String mUsername;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //this inflates out tab layout file.
    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_frag, null);
    comp_text=(TextView)x.findViewById(R.id.company_id);
    mail_text=(TextView)x.findViewById(R.id.email_id);
    gst_text= (TextView)x.findViewById(R.id.gst_id);
    initSharedPreferences();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged member->  "+mUsername, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return x;

}
private void initSharedPreferences() {
     mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUsername = mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.USERNAME, "");

    }
}
```

Here my Toast show **logged member-> **, that means musername have nothing to print and preferences are unable get.

I'm still confused this is my point of view if you want i can show where i saved preferences.

Help will be appreciated !
THANKS !

**EDIT 1 ----**
Here is my onResponse function where i saved preferences.

```
 public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                if(serverResponse.getMessage().equals(username)) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("LoggedIn",true);
                    editor.putString(Constants.USERNAME,serverResponse.getMessage());

                   boolean ok= editor.commit();


                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Saved: "+ok, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    goToProfile();
                }
            } else {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                ServerResponse errorResponse = null;
                try {
                    errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), ServerResponse.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Snackbar.make(loginButton,errorResponse.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post the code for how you save it in Login Activity?

Comment: are you saved username in default preference with same key?

Comment: @theanilpaudel sure

Comment: you have to provide the name of your shared preference in fragment to get sharepreference reference

Comment: Show. how you are saving name in Shared Preference

Comment: @Prashantsingh Can you show the code of inserting sharedprefs

Comment: i have edit the post with where i saved prefereences, please have a look at it

Comment: @AsadAli i didn't get it can tell me how and what you are saying actually i am newbie with preferences

Comment: can you add initialization of this `mSharedPreferences`?

Comment: @VadimEksler    **private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;**

Comment: this is the possible solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: ))) and `mSharedPreferences = ???`

Comment: @Prashantsingh What is the next issue you are facing?

Comment: @VadimEksler  mSharedPreferences =  i didn't add anything to it

Comment: so your mSharedPreferences  is null?

Comment: yes @VadimEksler

Comment: so you need to get it like in dock `mSharedPreferences = 
 context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java

Comment: thanks i figured out  and it worked @VadimEksler

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();;
                    editor.putBoolean("LoggedIn",true);
                    editor.putString(Constants.USERNAME,serverResponse.getMessage());

                   boolean ok= editor.commit();
```

And then in Fragment

```
mSharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE); ;
    mUsername = mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.USERNAME, "");
```

Comment: hey alright this worked but it renders my keep user logged in functionality ...now  i am unable to keep it logged in

Comment: This is how you use to save data using SharedPrefs, that functionality is your app's functionality and you have to figure out on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your response your answer helped me !